# Installation of sollya tool on windows

Tags: floating-point, mathematical-optimization, approximation

I've heard a lot of this free math tool sollya mentioned in many answers concerning approximations for floating point arithmetic.  I know it is not specifically a programming question, and i aimed to fit the case tools used regularily by programmers...

I decided to give it a shot and install it. Although I am not inexperienced in dealing with computers, I am desperate. I want to install and use sollya as a interactive tool and not as a C library.

I downloaded the latest version of sollya from the [download page](http://sollya.gforge.inria.fr/). The linked  [user manual](http://sollya.gforge.inria.fr/sollya-7.0/sollya.php) tells me to execute the executable file, and afterwards install several components.

The problem is: the .zip file does neither contain any executable file nor a valid starting file to compile the folder using e.g. visual studio. furthermore, i have found almost no further information concerning use and installation of sollya tool.

Comment: Sorry: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest (downvote however is not by me).

Comment: What makes you think that there is a GUI for this tool?

Comment: By the way, I accept that this is a (far out) case of "tools used regularily by programmers". Otherwise the question would be off-topic, because NOT using it as a C library removes this from being an immediate programming question.

Comment: @RubberBee I dont think that there is a GUI, but i expected to at least find  a command line based tool... The documentation tells me to run the executable file in order to use the interactive version. And yes, I know it is not specifically a programming question, and i aimed to fit the case tools used regularily by programmers... I will mention this in my question to avoid any further downvotes...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pre-built binaries for any platform are publically available.

As stated on the Sollya home page http://sollya.gforge.inria.fr/,

> In order to build Sollya, you will need: a C compiler (e.g., gcc), a
> C++ compiler (e.g., g++), GMP, MPFR, MPFI, FPLLL, and libxml2.

After installing all the prerequisites, the build procedure uses the usual GNU autotools paradigm:

```
./configure <optional switches...>
make
```

I'm not aware that anyone has built Sollya with MSFT or VS tools although, in theory, it should be possible.  Given my experience building Sollya for Mac OS X, I would think doing the same on Windows with Visual Studio could be quite "challenging."